# Fourier Series of a non periodic function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, mathematical-physics

In our textbook the given example-question is as follows (written in bold):

**Find a fourier series to represent $x-x^2$ from $x= -\pi$  to $x=  \pi$**

But the function given $x-x^2$ is non  periodic, what does it mean to have a fourier series for it, and why fourier series have a interval associated with it?

Any help is appreciated....
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider a periodic function $f$ with period length of $2\pi$. Then it is sufficient to define it on $[-\pi, \pi]$ (or any other interval of that length). In your case, $f(x)=x-x^2$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ (this restriction is crucial). Outside, it is repeated periodically.

Comment: Regarding your other question "Why do F-series have an interval associated with them?": This is part of the definition of Fourier-series, and should be contained in your textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the Fourier series of a function $f$ defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$ where $f(a) = f(b)$. Just use the definition that you have learned in class or in your book, and take the period length $b - a$. You can view this as extending the function periodically outside of $[a,b]$, or you can view the function as defined on the interval $[a,b]$ with the end points glued together.

This works also in many cases when the function so constructed is not continuous, as in your case when $f(x) = x - x^2$ does not satisfy $f(-π) = f(π)$. Just plug the values at the end points into the integral and it will work nicely.

Comment: The function is continuous, but the problem is it is not periodic. So is fourier series on it still valid?

Comment: The function is not continuous when defined on the space $[-π,π]$ where we identify $-π$ and $π$. As one approaches this point from above, the function value approaches $-π - π^2$, while when one approaches this point from below it grows close to $π - π^2$. Periodicity is automatic (or indeed equivalent) when the function is defined on a closed interval with the end points identified.

Comment: I know I am being stupid here but, I dont get this :Periodicity is automatic (or indeed equivalent) when the function is defined on a closed interval with the end points identified. Could you please explain this with an elaborate example.

Comment: The discontinuity is also evident if one uses the viewpoint that the function should be extended periodically with period $b - a$, that is $π - (-π) = 2π$. Again, when one approaches $π$ from below the function value approaches $π - π^2$, while when we approach $π$ from above the function value grows close to $-π - π^2$. When we approach from above, we must in this case use the periodicity property that $f(x) = f(x - 2π)$.

Comment: You are not being stupid - I am using very few words to explain this. What I meant is that if one glues the domain in the end points, the function becomes periodic in a sense, because we can keep going in a circle in the domain. Take the interval $[-π, π]$, bend it and connect $-π$ with $π$!

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Comment: You are welcome! And yes, the Fourier series is amazingly still valid, meaning that it will converge to the same function everywhere except for the point of discontinuity.